# Android non-Activity getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem by reading getSharedPreferences from non-Activity class to set playlist in player... In my Activity I take string variable from edittext to get path of folder to work with audio files...

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


String ppp;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    String PATH = getSharedPreferences("PATH", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("path", ppp);
    if (PATH == null){
        ..........
            ...........
        path_tv.setText("folder is undefined");
    }
    else {
        path_tv.setText("folder defined: /mnt/sdcard/" + PATH);
    }
    set_path.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (path_edit.getText().toString().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "folder is undefined", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
            ppp = path_edit.getText().toString();
            getSharedPreferences("PATH", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putString("path", ppp)
            .commit();
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + ppp);
            boolean success = false;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdir();
                if (success) Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ".....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            String PATH = getSharedPreferences("PATH", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("path", ppp);
            path_tv.setText("........ /mnt/sdcard/" + PATH);
            path_edit.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

So, in activity I can change and save value of String in shared preferences... But ho can I do it from public class...? Appreciate any examples...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to use [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object. This is a dirty hack but none the less sometimes helpful.

First you need a static member in your Application class, so:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Since Application object is always created before any activity is created and run and is kept throughout application lifetime you can always be sure you will have proper one.

Then in your code simply call `MyApplication.getInstance()` and you will have global app context.

Remember to declare `MyApplication` in manifest.

Comment: Ok, I have added MyApp to manifest and as a class with extends... Now in my class I have created constructor where added AppApp.getInstance();

Comment: Can you give stack trace? possibly on my email - when we solve your problem we can edit your question or my answer.
I've been using solution like this several times.

Comment: It works fine, but if the app goes to the background for some minutes, and the user returns, it is possible that the instance not exist. I have to initialize this variable in all the activities, in that case it is the same to pass the argument in each call of the class that needs the activity instance.

Answer (score 9):

You have to get the context passed to your class method:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Test t = new Test("Show Preference: ");
        getSharedPreferences("PATH", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit()
        .putString("p", "preference")
        .commit();
        t.showToast(this.getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

TestClass:

```
public class Test {
    private String s;

    public Test(String s){
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void showToast (Context c){
        String pref = c.getSharedPreferences("PATH", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("p", "Error");
        Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), s + pref, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Hope to help

Answer (score 1):

you  need to pass the context in the constructor of the class and then use this 
   context to perform the read or write operation of share preference like as

```
           public class xyx{
            public  xyx(Context context){
             this.context= context
             }

     Now use this context
```

Answer (score 0):

add MainActivity.this. before getSharedPreferences